# Head to head movement (V to T) in Haitian Creole

Tags: movement

Bouki pa konnen Boukinet
(S)   (NEG)  (V)         (O)

Why is there no V-T raising in this example? Is it because there is no adverb?

Comment: This is French?

Comment: Oops, it's actually Haitian Creole

Comment: V-to-T raising is an obsolete concept.

Comment: @Atamiri: It would be more  helpful if you could mention something about why the concept is obsolete, or what it has been replaced by.